# Some currency signs missing in Java currency API

Tags: java, currency

I'm writing some currency conversion code in Java and and using this API to build up an internal lookup table of currencies

```
final Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for (final Locale locale : locales) {
   final Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
   String sign = currency.getSymbol(locale)
   String code = currency.getCurrencyCode()
     /* do something with them */
}
```

I've two observations so far.

1. This listing does not return a Rupee sign  in the native script https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign. It returns Rs. instead
2. Similarly for the Russian Ruble, it returns руб instead of the Ruble sign in the native script https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruble_sign

Many international currencies have signs in the Latin script and native script. Java doesn't seem to be consistent in what it returns. Am I running into a limitation or is my API usage incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code for Indian Rupee sign, and it seems to be working perfectly.
The symbol is available for locale `hi_IN`

[image: Rupees symbol for hi_IN locale]

But for `en_IN`, 'Rs' symbol is available

[image: Rs symbol for en_IN locale]

Make sure you use right locale. :)

Comment: So the rupee sign you see is a dated one. I was hoping to see ₹ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign

Comment: Btw, thanks for taking a swing at the code and sharing your results!